# Can Webpack fullfill the full DevOps pipeline process for cloud native apps?

Tags: jenkins, webpack, single-page-application, devops

I am the only designer and developer for web/app development at my company. We want to create cloud native apps for cloud deployment and are looking at following the [principles](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/beyond-the-twelve-factor-app) of the `twelve factor app` methodology. With very little experience in the DevOps/Jenkins Pipeline environment, I was wondering if strictly using Webpack for my DevOps flow would be adequate for production deployment. I understand Webpack has some testing and validation features built in (ESLint, Mocha, etc). I envision that I would run my SPA (single page app) via Webpack for compilation and then I'd push the compiled/dist files to a Cloud Foundry environment (PaaS) for deployment.

Would this be adequate for cloud native development these days or is it recommended to use the full Jenkins pipeline for DevOps? I am not sure how Webpack would be able to use Git as the codebase, but it looks like all the other DevOps features are there in Webpack (and I thought I read more companies were shifting to strictly Webpack for simplicity and less reliance on Jenkins dependencies).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, webpack is so powerful, i guess the only thing you are going to run into is running tests. AFAIK there is no way to run tests directly from webpack.

I don't think jenkins can be totally replaced by a webpack instance, for eg: there is no way to consume code from your github automagically the same way that jenkins does. Webpack will act more like an agregator of tools, other than a CI/CD agent.